# Github: How to access same repository from different computers

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository which i can access from my machine, but i want to grant permission to other machine for access same repository (for push or pull)

So i am not sure how i fix it.

Any suggesstion would be appreciated

Comment: Even you can access **a same repository** from **2/many different folders** in **same computer**.

Answer (score 9):

**(1)** Your wish is Git's default feature. For example: In first computer:

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxxxxx/personal_finance.git
```

In second computer:

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxxxxx/personal_finance.git
```

**(2)** For Git user account identity, in side Git local repository, In first computer:

```
git config user.email "xxxxxxx@hotmail.com"
git config user.name "xxxxxxx"
```

In second computer:

```
git config user.email "xxxxxxx@hotmail.com"
git config user.name "xxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 3):

Sign in with the same account...

Answer (score 0):

You can log in to your account from ANY computer and access your files.  I use GitHub on my home computer primarily, but I just logged in to my account at work, and as you can see from the image, I can work on something from here if I wanted to.

[image]

That's the beauty of GitHub.  You're not restricted to a specific device.  You can work on a multitude of devices.  You can also add **people** to your projects, if you need to, like this:

[image]

Hope that helps!